# настройка ManyToMany с помощью аннотаций JPA

Tags: java, база-данных, jpa

Есть 2 сущности которые я сделал следующим образом (ниже), как видно поле `tagName` у `Tag` должно быть уникальным. Если попробовать сохранить `Article` с набором `Tag` `tagName` одного из которого уже существует, возникает ошибка. Есть ли возможность настроить отношение `@ManyToMany` с помощью аннотаций так, чтобы при подобном сохранении, если `Tag` с `tagName` уже существует, то либо не сохранять его, либо обновлять?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String tagName;

    public Tag(String tagName){
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    public Article(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "article_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")}
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока решил проблему так. Объявил `tagName` у `Tag` как `@Id` и удалил у него поле `id`. Изменил `CascadeType.ALL` у `Article` в аннотации `@ManyToMany` на `CascadeType.REFRESH` и перед сохранением `Article` сохраняю транзитивные `Tag` не `save()` методом, а `saveOrUpdate()`, что позволяет избежать проблемы описанной выше. Теперь сущности выглядят следующим образом:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String tagName;

    public Tag(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    public Article(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "article_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")}
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```